# Unable to upload cordova apk in app store due to security vulnerabilities

Tags: cordova, android-security

I have uploaded an app 2 years ago having apache version less than 3.5.0
I unpublished this app and created a new app with same account and uploaded apk in alpha from latest cordova version (7.0.1) and all latest plugins, but still I am getting the error: 
 `Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy.` 
and in alerts its showing that uploaded apk having the cordova version less than 3.5
Please help incase anyone get resolve this.

Comment: Did you copy files from the old app to the new one?

Comment: I have just copied my www folder, which contains html/css/js. Otherwise all the things are newly installed, all plugins and platforms.

Comment: Make sure you don't have an old cordova.js in there

Comment: No, there is no cordova.js in www, its taking it from platform

Comment: same project is successfully uploaded in iOS platform but I am surprised why its not uploading in Play store.. :(

Comment: That's because Apple doesn't complain about old Cordova versions. Can you upload the project somewhere?

Comment: Yes I can share project, can you please give your email ID?